# Mechanize Error - Python

Tags: python, mechanize

I am attempting to use mechanize to veiw and collect data from various websites. I have run across an error that states

```
No handlers could be found for logger "mechanize"
```

This error does not give a specific location for where it the error occurred which makes it very difficult to debug. I have looked online and have seen that the mechanize version 0.1.11 has solved this problem. I have downloaded a newer version of mechanize and imagine this should no longer be an issue. My code that is causing this problem is

```
def KEGG(textfile):  
    KEGGString = ''  
    KEGGList = []  
    original = open('Final.txt', 'r')    
    for row in original:      
        data = re.split("(#|\t)", row) ##splits text files by tabs into separate strings  
        new_items = [x if x!='\t' else 'None' for x in data]  ##replaces extra tabs with "None"  
        KEGGList.append(new_items[-1])  
    KEGGHeaderless = KEGGList[1:] ## Removes header (Cross-Reference (KEGG)) from the list.  
    KEGGHeaderless = [s.replace(';', '') for s in KEGGHeaderless]  
    fo = open('KEGG Description.txt', 'w')  
    for row in KEGGHeaderless:  
       geneID = row  
       base2 = 'http://www.genome.jp/dbget-bin/www_bget?'  
       url = base2 + geneID  
       br = Browser()  
       br.set_handle_robots(False)  
       br.open(url)  
       for line in KEGGHeaderless:  
            targetURL = '/dbget-bin/get_linkdb?-t+pathway+' + row  
            try:  
                site = br.follow_link(url=targetURL)  
                br.open(site)  
                page = br.response().read()  
                fo.write(page)  
            except:   
                fo.write(line + "None\n")   
    fo.close()
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mechanize` uses the `logging` module.
If your script does not supply a logging handler, then logging calls from within `mechanize` can result in this error.

To supply a generic handler, try adding

```
import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG)
```

to your script. This will show all logging messages of level `DEBUG` or higher.
If you only want to show critical errors, you could change it to

```
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.CRITICAL)
```

Or, if you want to disable logging, you could use

```
logging.disable(logging.DEBUG)
```

See [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/logging.html) for other options and logging levels.